# Help with plotting the function?

Tags: plotting

I'm trying to plot the result of the following :

```
 ClearAll;
 P = 50; k = 0.235; Cx = 4.2; Rho = 1 ; r = 0.001; L = 0.006; l = 
 1.25*10^-7; a = 1.1*10^-7; beta = 2*Sqrt[a*Pi]/l;
 Q = Rho/(Pi * r^2 * NIntegrate[Exp[-k/(P*Cx)], {x, 0, 1.25*L}]);

 T[z_, t_] := (Q*l^2*a^2 + 2*Q - 2*Q*Exp[-a*l])/2*a^3*k + Sum[Exp[-beta ^2*t]*(4*Q*l/(a*k*n*Pi^2)),{n,1,1000}] - Cos[beta*z/Sqrt[a]] - Q/k - 
   Q*Exp[-a]/(a^2*k);
 sol = T[z, t]
```

I"m supposed to get somthing like this:
[image]

But I'm getting flat surface.

Comment: Please add the code that you are using to plot.

Comment: Because of the huge exponents involved I suspect round-off errors. Try changing all approximate decimal values to exact rationals, change `NIntegrate` to `Integrate` and then try this `Plot3D[T[z, t]+1.4942442034098676618539243100*^22,{t,0,8/100},{z,0,8/100}]` which shows a large flat area ~=0 and a sharp rising edge near t==0